# send complex and simple parameter to web api using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

i write web api.

web api controller:

```
public class TaskApiController : ApiController
    {
     [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult PostNewTask(string xx,string yy,CommonTask Task)
        {
    ...
    }
}
```

and ajax:

```
var task = new Object();

task.Description = 'kjk';
task.ID = null;


var req = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3641/api/TaskApi',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {"xx":'admin',"yy":'123',"task": JSON.stringify(task) },
    type: 'Post',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    }
});

req.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

and WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

when run ajax, return error:
**No action was found on the controller 'TaskApi' that matches the request**

Comment: Is the definition and initialize of the parameters in Action and Ajax correct?

While I define a parameter (CommonTask Task) for action and set it to an AJAX with "data:  JSON.stringify(task)"  it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Always feed the POST methods with class type parameters. Please do the following modification on the API and JavaScript.

1. Create a model class

<pre>
public class Model
{
    public string xx { get; set; }
    public string yy { get; set; }
    public CommonTask Task { get; set; }  
}
</pre>

Then modify your Web API to accept a type of your class model
<pre>
public class TaskApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostNewTask([FromBody] Model model)
    {

    }
}
</pre>

Change your ajax method to pass a json object similar to the Model class

<pre>
var task = new Object();

task.Description = 'kjk';
task.ID = null;

var data = {
    "xx": 'admin',
    "yy": '123',
    "task" : JSON.stringify(task)
};

var req = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3641/api/TaskApi',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {"model": JSON.stringify(data) },
    type: 'Post',
    success: function (message) {
        alert('success');
    }
});

req.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
</pre>
```